# XSD Pattern restriction. How to get a shorthand

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I have an XSD grammar where one SimpleType which should be restricted to a 6 comma-separated numeric values. That is, each element is of the form:

```
-?\d*\.?\d+\s*
```

As I need a 6-tuple I can write the following pattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*"/>
```

I wanted to short it. I've tried with the following pattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="(-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,){5}\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*" />
```

But seems to be wrong. I cannot recognise the error. Can anybody tell me why is this wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what way does it fail?

It works for me (with Saxon as the schema validator). With the schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
  <xs:element name="top">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="(-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,){5}\s*-?\d*\.?\d+\s*" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

this document is valid:

```
<top>1,2,3,4,5,6</top>
```

and this one is invalid:

```
<top>1,2,3,4,5</top>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. True, I didnt mention in which way it is not working. I am testing it with the following element. <top>1, 1.2, 0, 1.56, 1, 1</top>. It fails using XMLspy.

Comment: You still don't say how it's failing - but since it's Altova, I can't help you further anyway.

Comment: I don't think your regex allows whitespace after the commas, only before.